# Chat 'enable desktop notification' should probably be '...notifications'

Tags: bug, chat, grammar, plurals

> enable desktop notification

and

> disable desktop notification

don't sound right - shouldn't it be plural?

You're enabling/disabling it for *multiple notifications*...

> enable desktop notification**s**

and

> disable desktop notification**s**

[image]